# Is it true that functors which are surjective on objects are obviously essentially surjective?

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations, morita-equivalence

I am asking this as I have established a functor F between categories C and D such that F is faithful, full and surjective on objects. Can I say that F is an equivalence of categories? I think so but need some expert comment for assurance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is obvious if you write the definitions of being “surjective on objects” and “essentially surjective”.

Comment: @azif00  It helps to also remember that every object is isomorphic to itself (or at least to something).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is obvious that a functor which is surjective on objects is also essentially surjective on objects.
In your given situation, it is therefore okay to state that “the functor $F$ is faithful, full and surjective on objects, and therefore an equivalence of categories”.¹

---

¹ Assuming that it is known to the reader that a functor which is faithful, full and essentially surjective is an equivalence of categories.